# Symfony3 queryBuilder how to search with OR and how to search for substring?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am making an app with Symfony and I am creating the database and repository. I need to make a query that selects from table `orders` where the date is today (the field `date` is `datetime`) and where either the `user` property matches `search` variable OR the `product` property matches that `search` variable. The match also must be case insensitive. Simply put - the user selects the date period (today, all time, or last 7 days) and types in a string and I need to get all orders that are in the specified date (today,  all time or last 7 days) and either the `product` in the order contains the `search` or the `user` property contains the `search`. Here is what I have so far

```
 $queryBuilder->
              where('DATE_DIFF(orders.date, CURRENT_DATE()) = 0')->
              andWhere("order.user LIKE '%search%'")->
              setParameter('search',$search);
```

I have to match for both `user` and `product` properties and I need to match a part of string, not the whole string.

For example if the user searches for `mike` I need to match the user `Mike Johnson` or the product `mike`.

I thought about using `orWhere` for both but it will just match the date even if both other searches are wrong. So I used `andWhere`, however now how am I supposed to add the third criteria? I thought about adding OR in the `addWhere`.

I have seen many answers here, but most of them are really old. Some are from 5 years ago. I have no idea if 'DATE_DIFF' is the right way to go or if the `LIKE` is also the proper way to do it. In Symfony using Doctrine I could go for a simple query with `SELECT` and write it all down. However, I want to use the full capacity of the queryBuilder and use as least amount of key words like `LIKE` or `OR' (pun intended) as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to change this:

```
andWhere("order.user LIKE '%search%'")
```

to this:

```
andWhere("order.user LIKE '%search%' OR product.user LIKE '%search%'")
```

Or you can try something more complex like this (I don't have tried now this but the concept is clear):

```
$queryBuilder
     ->where('DATE_DIFF(orders.date, CURRENT_DATE()) = 0')
     ->andWhere($qb->expr()->orX(
          $qb->expr()->like('order.user', '%search%'),
          $qb->expr()->like('product.user', '%search2%')
     ))
     setParameters(
        [
            'search' => $search,
            'search2' => $search,
        ]
     );
```

[Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

Comment: Thank you, I thought of doing that as well, but is there a way to use function provided by the queryBuilder that could be from some use to me?

Comment: Update answer with a new solution but I think that for your case is better the first @ЛуциПетков